# return all unique directories within a hierarchy

Tags: php, recursion, iterator, directory

I'm using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to scan for all files and folders within a given root dir.  This works fine, but I'd like to keep track of all of the *unique* directories in that list, so I'm not sure that `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is the way to go.

I have a directory structure of

`-a
 ->b
  ->c
-one
 ->two
  ->three`

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function test($dir){

    $in_dir = 'none';
    $currdir = 'none';

    $thisdir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($thisdir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach($files as $object){
    //if this is a directory... find out which one it is.
    if($object->isDir()){

        //figure out if we have changed directories...
        $currdir = realpath($object->getPath());

        if(strpos($currdir, '.') == false){
        $test = strcmp($currdir, $prevdir);
        if($test){
            echo "current dir changing: ", $currdir, "\n";
            $prevdir = $currdir;
        }
        }
    }
    }
}

test('fold');   
?>
```

What I get from that is the following:

`current dir changing: /Users/<usr>/Desktop/test/fold`

`current dir changing: /Users/<usr>/Desktop/test/fold/a`

`current dir changing: /Users/<usr>/Desktop/test/fold/a/b`

`current dir changing: /Users/<usr>/Desktop/test/fold`

`current dir changing: /Users/<usr>/Desktop/test/fold/one`

`current dir changing: /Users/<usr>/Desktop/test/fold/one/two`

...But I only want the *unique* directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perhaps the method of object comparison in the loop that returns duplicates, as the iterator moves up and down the directory tree as it parses through folders.

The following worked for me. I also use `array_unique()` confirm no dupes as a redundancy.

```
$dirArray = []; // the array to store dirs
$path = realpath('/some/folder/location');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

// loop through all objects and store names in dirArray[]
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
  if ($object->isDir()) {
    $dirArray[] = $name;
  }
}

// make sure there are no dupes
$result = array_unique($dirArray);

// print array out
print_r($result);
```